# My SDK componets are not installing via the Android Studio Installer?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[INSTALLER second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJHIW.png)

I am using Windows 10. This is what it is showing in the second step of the official Android Studio installer. As far as I know it should show 3 components  there. The SDK components is missing? what should I do?

Comment: proceed your installed sdk is embeded with it !!

Comment: Right I got it. Thanks.